# Help with calculus conceptual question

Tags: calculus, solid-of-revolution

Need help for AP calc AB test coming up but am a bit stumped about how to solve this question:

Suppose a region R has an area A and lies above the x-axis. When R is rotated about the x-axis, it sweeps out a solid with volume V1. When R is rotated around the line y = -k (k is a positive integer), it sweeps out a solid of volume V2. Express V2 in terms of V1, k, and A.

With this phrasing, it doesn't sound like A is the area of the cross section formed. For V1, it can be either a disk or a ring/washer depending on if it touches the x-axis. However, in the absence of an equation, not sure where to start (unless I'm misunderstanding A).

If anyone could provide some guidance or hints it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The exam is in 14 hours my man 

Comment: nothing touches the x-axis, the region lies above and the line  $y=-k$ lies below, so both volumes will be of ring/washer type.

Comment: But in the absence of an equation and R as a blob with no clear dimensions, how would this be set up? Also I think the problem is more the lack of numbers or equations so hopefully the test would otherwise go well haha

Comment: [Pappus's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pappus's_centroid_theorem) comes to mind.